# python library socketIO-client doesn't work on os x

Tags: python, socket.io, network-programming

```
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
    from socketIO_client import SocketIO

    try:
        socket = SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 5000, wait_for_connection=False)
        socket.emit('my message', 'Hello world!')
        socket.wait()
    except ConnectionError:
        print('The server is down. Try again later.')
```

After running SocketIO server, The piece of code works well on ubuntu, but doesn't work on OS X 10.12.2, it always gets stuck in "`socket = SocketIO('127.0.0.1', 5000, wait_for_connection=False)`".
Can someone tell me something wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. because I opened the http proxy for my mac terminal.